# Sending data from one tab/page to another on different servers

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, server

I've got a shopping cart page that contains some products. For ease let's call this page 1. Each product on page 1 has a button that opens an editor in a new tab, let's call this page 2.

People can edit the product on page 2 and click on a button that saves the changes in a database and closes the tab. At this point page 1 should refresh and show the changes that were made in page 2.

At the moment I do this by checking every 2 seconds for changes using ajax requests on page 1. Like this:

```
var editorcheck = function() {
    order_id = $('.order_id_input').val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:"payprocess/editorcheck.php",
        data:({order_id: order_id}),
        success:function(data){
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                var changedtotalstatus = obj[i].changedtotalstatus;
                if(changedtotalstatus == 'yes'){
                    location.reload(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
// Execture editorcheck function every 2 seconds
var interval = 2000;
setInterval(editorcheck, interval);
```

This means every 2 seconds a HTTP request is made even when someone does nothing and leaves open page 1. When a lot of visitor are on the website this is a bad idea.

There must be a better way to do this. I found out about websockets but my shared hosting provider does not give me enough access to make those work, so those are off the table.

Instead of checking every 2 seconds in a database with an ajax call is there a way to send a signal/data from page 2 to page 1 the moment the changes are saved and page 2 closes?

Page 1 is on my shared hosting and page 2 is on a VPS (which I have access to). So they are not on the same server.

What is the best solution for this?

Comment: Run a websocket server on the vps instead, then. You can do whatever you want there. If you want real time communication without the Ajax overhead then websockets is pretty much the standard option for web applications. Possibly the only option, in fact. There's server sent events too, but as the name suggests it's a one way communication channel which may or may not be ok for you. Or since you seems to be describing a situation which only ever involves comms between two pages running in the same browser simultaneously , you could just use Javascript e.g. the postMessage function

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: I see the postMessage function works for popups or pages with iframes in it. But what about in my case a new tab? As far as i know a popup is different from a new tab.

Comment: If the second tab was opened by an action on the first tab then there's very little difference as far as Javascript and security is concerned. many users choose popups to appear like tabs anyway, it's more of a visual difference than a technical one